# What sets the language of iCal invitations?

Tags: icloud, ical

I am using Mac OS X 10.6 configured for English. I am using iCloud configured for English. Why are iCal invitations sent in German?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to [appleid.apple.com](https://appleid.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MyAppleId.woa/) and set the preferred language for your account.

**iCloud** calendar invitations will use that language.

Comment: You are right. It was set to German. Now I guess the correct question is: _why_ was it set to German???